# How to add a WHERE clause to a Lucene query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, lucene

I have the following method for searching in a `Lucene` database.

```
public List search(String search, String sortPlace) {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Spot.class).get();

    Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("name", "description", "address", "website")
            .matching(search).createQuery();
//Query must also match *sortPlace* and the boolean *enabled*.

    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Spot.class);

    List<Spot> spotList = null;
    try {
        spotList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        System.out.println("NRE: " + nre);
    }


    return spotList;

}
```

This function implements fuzzy search on the following fields:

*name*, *description*,  *address* and *website*.

**The issue is:** 
The search results must also match the value for the field *enabled* and *sortPlace* (which could be Restaurant, Bar, Hotel etc.) but doesn't.

I guess I need some sort of WHERE clause on top of the existing query.
Hopefully somebody can help me out with that, thank you!